# PHP: go through multidimentional array and get array of keys for searched element`s key

Tags: php, optimization, multidimensional-array, key

I tried to get array of keys of searched element`s key in multidimensional array. For example, my initial array is:

```
$f['Kitchen']['Dishes']['Mantovarka']=3;
$f['Kitchen']['Dishes']['Castrool']=91;
$f['Kitchen']['Dishes']['Separator']=10;
$f['Kitchen']['Product']=18;
$f['Kitchen']['Textile']=19;
$f['Kitchen']['Blue things One']['Juicemaker']=25;
$f['Kitchen']['Blue things One']['Freegener']=13;
$f['Kitchen']['Blue things']['Microwave']=4;
$f['Kitchen']['Blue things']['Iron']=24;
```

If I try to get array of keys for 'Separator' key with this function:

```
$index=0; $array =[];
function getArrayOfkeys($needle, $haystack,$original,$array,$index) {

    $index++;
    $exists = false;

    if(is_array($haystack)){

        foreach ($haystack as $key => $val) {
            $array[$index]=$key;

            if($key == $needle){
                $exists = true;
                break;
            }elseif(is_array($val)){
                return getArrayOfkeys($needle, $val,$original,$array,$index);
            }

        }

    }else{
        $index--;
    }

    if($exists==true){
        return $array;
    }
    else{

        // I need here logic!!!    
    }
}
```

it returns me:

```
[
    1 => 'Kitchen'
    2 => 'Dishes'
    3 => 'Separator'
]
```

it is fine!

But when I try to get array of keys of 'Juicemaker' or 'Iron' or 'Product'. It is not working, because I can`t call my getArrayOfkeys() function after element:

```
$f['Kitchen']['Dishes']['Separator']=10;
```

1. How can I call again after abovementioned element?

I want to get for 'Juicemaker' key `['Kitchen', 'Blue things One', 'Juicemaker']`.

For 'Product' key `['Kitchen','Product']`.

For 'Iron' key `['Kitchen', 'Blue things','Iron']`

2. My function seems to me very unoptimized, help me, please, with optimize it.

Comment: it would be better if you have shown the initial array and the expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all parent keys of an array from a given child key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814094/how-to-find-all-parent-keys-of-an-array-from-a-given-child-key)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this function:

```
function findKeyPath($arr, $key, $path = '') {
    foreach($arr as $k => $value) {
        if(is_array($arr[$k])) {
            $ret = findKeyPath($arr[$k], $key, $path.$k.',');
            if(is_array($ret)) {
                return $ret;
            }
        }else if($k == $key) {
            return explode(',', $path.$key);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

print_r(findKeyPath($f, 'Juicemaker'));
//Output: Array ( [0] => Kitchen [1] => Blue things One2 [2] => Juicemaker )
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/YJD7q

I hope this will help you.